# Preventing multiple web notifications?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, websocket, web-notifications

I'm using websocket to receive notifications from server side, when I got a notification, I show a desktop notification using the `Web Notification` API, the problem is, if I'm opening this page in multiple tabs, I'd receive multiple duplicated desktop notifications...

I've tried to use cookies to store a flag, say when tab1 get the notification, it set a flag in the cookie, when tab2 get the same notification, it checks for the cookie flag, if there is one, tab2 wouldn't show a desktop notification. Sounds nice right? but it doesn't work, maybe tab1 and tab2 receive the notification from websocket so synchronous that the cookie is not set yet?

Comment: Duplicate with answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17314074/227176

Comment: Notification with `tag` https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues/3517#issuecomment-237151402

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you get just datas from websocket, you can create a notification IF cookie say yes ELSE just ignore...